# Spark Streaming | Write different data frames to multiple tables in parallel

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

I am reading data from Kafka and loading into data warehouse, from one Kafka topic I am
creating a data frame and after applying the required transformation I am creating multiple DFs out of it and loading those DFs to different tables, but this operation is happening in sequence. Is there a way I can parallelize this table load process?

```
root
|-- attribute1Formatted: array (nullable = true)
|    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
|    |    |-- accexecattributes: struct (nullable = true)
|    |    |    |-- id: string (nullable = true)
|    |    |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
|    |    |    |-- primary: boolean (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- accountExecUUID: string (nullable = true)
|-- attribute2Formatted: struct (nullable = true)
|    |-- Jake-DOT-Sandler@xyz.com: struct (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- id: string (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- primary: boolean (nullable = true)
```

have created two different datframes respectively for attribute1Formatted and attribute2Formatted and further these DFs are getting saved into database in different tables.

Comment: Can you post the code that you are using? The spark parts, simplifying output the business part

Answer (score 0):

I don't have much knowledge of spark streaming but I believe streaming are iterative micro-batch, and in spark batch execution each action has one sink/output. So you can't store it in different tables with one execution.

Now,

1. if you write it in one table, reader can simply read only the column that they require. I mean: do you really need to store it in different places?
2. You can write it twice, filtering the fields that are not required

- both write action will execute the computation of the full dataset, then remove not required columns
- if the full dataset computation is long, you can cache it before the filtering+write

Comment: Initially I was writing into one table but the problem is DF is having arrays and when exploding it is creating all different combination of rows and we want to store array as a separate table.

caching I am doing  but I was thinking when there is no dependency between the tables its better to load them in parallel.